# How to import date and convert time zone?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, subquery

I have a CSV file with a date field in `UTC`.
I want to import data into redshift in `EST`.
Is it possible to specify the timezone in the `COPY` or should I use `UPDATE`?

I tried this but it does not work. *Error: subquery returns more than one row query*

```
UPDATE myTable
SET DATE = (
        SELECT convert_timezone('Europe/Paris', DATE)
        FROM myTable
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE myTable
    SET date = convert_timezone('Europe/Paris', date);
```